Anchor build completes without error, but no .so file
I'm trying to build Raydium amm-cpi. Everything went well, anchor build completes without an error but there is no .so file in the target/deploy/ dir.
target/idl/amm_cpi.json and target/types/amm_cpi.ts files are created correctly.
I already tried to remove the target dir and did cargo clean before the build.
Updated anchor-cli from 0.28.0 to 0.29.0
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "amm-cpi"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "amm_cpi"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
amm-anchor = { git = "https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions", package = "amm-anchor" }
solana-program = ">=1.16, <1.18"

Anchor.toml
[toolchain]

[features] seeds = false skip-lint = false

[programs.devnet] amm_cpi = "3igNEs6GbvsAgEicsLTkduyhVFWXNkGerQobX1fdZdf9"

[registry] url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider] cluster = "Devnet" wallet = "/Users/me/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts] test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"

My env:
macOS 13.3 (22E252)
anchor-cli 0.29.0
solana-cli 1.17.34 (src:b04a806c; feat:3746964731, client:SolanaLabs)


You are looking in the wrong directories,
The .so and program keypair file will be found in the /target/deploy directory.

Thanks for your comment but there is no /target/deploy directory after build. Only as I mentioned idl and types

Remove the target directory and build it using cargo-sbf. use rm -r target && cargo build-sbf

Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. I tried with
rm -r target && cargo build-sbf and rm -r target && cargo clean && cargo build-sbf . using cargo build-sbf do not create targetdir at all

This is the output when I run rm -rf target && carbo build-sbf --verbose
https://codeshare.io/EkVKq8
